# Checking whether current date time is greater than or equal to date and time from the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, time, timestamp

I am creating an application for a training management system. I have to check if thge current date and time is greater than the date and time in the db. If so, hide some buttons. But my code is not working.

I don't know what I have done wrong. I am stuck on this for hours now. The date in db is in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` and time is in `H:i`. Here is what I've tried:

```
    end_Time = data.end_Time; // to get the time from db
    var CurrentDate = new Date();
    var arrDate = end_Time[0].end_date.split("-");
    var dbDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1] - 1, arrDate[0]);
    var hours = CurrentDate.getHours();
    var minutes = ("0" + (CurrentDate.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
    var Current_Time = hours + ":" + minutes;

    if (dbDate < CurrentDate) {
        if ((end_Time[0].end_time) < Current_Time) {
            $("#updateTrainingButton").hide();
            $("#sendInvitationButton").hide();
            $("#cancelTrainingButton").hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is not working? What happens? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error message..But the buttons are bnot hiding.. I think i have done something wrong in getting the time and date.But dont know what..!!

Comment: _Check_ the date values you are creating.

Comment: Do you have a working link?

Comment: show us the HTML Code also ??? and also show the date time format  example from the database

Comment: Throw in some alert messages or console.log calls for debugging.

Comment: There is not much HTML code here.. I just wanna hide 3 buttons..no HTML involved here

Comment: The `div`s you want to hide are not in your code. Please post the html to them. And the code you posted I suppose is inside a function, or?

Comment: here arrDate is `["28", "06", "2013"] `and dbDate for the same I get is `Fri Jun 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: yes it is inside a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//i think it should be like this:

```
if (dbDate < CurrentDate) {
    $("#updateTrainingButton").hide();
    $("#sendInvitationButton").hide();
    $("#cancelTrainingButton").hide();
}else if(dbDate == CurrentDate){
    if ((end_Time[0].end_time) < Current_Time) {
        $("#updateTrainingButton").hide();
        $("#sendInvitationButton").hide();
        $("#cancelTrainingButton").hide();
    }
}
```